# Apollo: How to handle cache after graphql error?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I know how to update the cache after successful mutation (using `update`).
I know how to handle the errors themselves (using `try/catch` and a global `onError` config on the client).

How can I update the cache after error in mutation?
I need this because I'm handling per-field loading field inside the cache (as local `@client` fields), and I want to set them to `false` after the mutation has failed (and also return the previous value of the field if needed). Do you have a better concept to handling per-field loading indicator?

I'm currently using withApollo to get the client and then using `client.cache.writeData` to manually manipulate the cache. it kinda works but I'm having rendering issues - I can see the change in the console/developer tools, but not in the actual element, and after another change in the element it takes the updated loading value.

Is there another way?

Comment: I think the way you thinking is fine. Can you try client.writeQuery?
Other issue can be with your code, that the client is not rerendering the new value to the dom.(This one is not related to the graphql data flow)

Comment: If you using react, some memorized issue also can appear

Comment: @Peter yep, `client.writeQuery` did the job, though I used Daniel's advice and used writeFragment to be more future proof. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `client.writeData` instead of `cache.writeData` -- the latter does not trigger reactive updates in the UI while the former does. Once you migrate to version 3.0 of the client, you'll need to use `writeQuery` or `writeFragment` instead because `writeData` will be removed so you might consider changing to one of those two methods instead.

Comment: Thanks! perfect explanation. I was hoping there's some built-in feature to access the cache after mutation error (much like in `update` when successful) which will save the need to use `withApollo`. But if there isn't - this is the info that I was missing.

Comment: @DavidAvikasis you can utilize `onError` as a callback but that is only passed the error as as argument. If you're using hooks (and you really should be since the HOCs are deprecated), then the hook result will actually include the client.